# How to run specific scenario from a feature file without changing the path of feature file in cukesfeaturefile?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, bdd, feature-file

This is my cukesfile

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/resources/features/SellerApp/Dashboard/QuickSearch/Dashboard_QuickSearch.feature"},
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-report.html"},
        glue={"steps"},
        tags = "@run",
        monochrome = true)
public class CukesFeaturesRunnerTest {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void executeBeforeTests() {
        if (StringUtils.equalsAnyIgnoreCase(getConfigValue("env"), "ci")) {
            System.out.println("Running test in headless mode");
            Configuration.headless = true;
        }
    Configuration.headless = true;
    Configuration.timeout = 12000;
    Configuration.browserSize = "1600x900";
    PluginsApi pluginsApi = new PluginsApi();
    XolaApi xolaApi = new XolaApi();

    if (StringUtils.equalsAnyIgnoreCase(getConfigValue("env"), "ci")) {
        if (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(System.getenv("GO_JOB_NAME"), "traveler-app")) {
            xolaApi.verifyX2TravelerAppIsRunning();
            xolaApi.verifyX2SellerAppIsRunning();
        } else {
            xolaApi.verifyX2SellerAppIsRunning();
        }
    }

    pluginsApi.getAllInstalledPluginId();
}

@AfterClass
public static void executeAfterTests() {
}
```

}

- The problem here is whenever I want to run any specific scenario, I have to give that feature file path value for features under cucumberOption.I want to make it in such a way I don't have to specify the path anymore, should pick up the scenario if @run tags are added to any scenario.

Comment: Which version of Cucumber are you using?

Comment: 7.14.0 this is the cucumber version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cucumber will execute all features in a directory and its sub directories. So to execute all features in the `features` directory you'd use.

```java
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/resources/features},
...
)
```

Then to select a single scenario, tag it with `@run` and use:

```java
@CucumberOptions(
    features = {"src/test/resources/features},
    tags = "@run",
...
)
```

Or if you are on a recent version of Cucumber and using an IDE such as IDEA you can also select scenario to run from the UI.

Doing this does mean that the `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` are not invoked anymore. So you should replace these with the `@BeforeAll` and `@AfterAll` hooks from Cucumber(note: pull the code out of the runner and put with your other step definitions or Cucumber won't find them).

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-java#beforeall--afterall